# How I make input value first-letter uppercase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have made all buttons first letter uppercase and all other lowercase. But I don't know how to make it happen with input value.
Why i want this is because if someone/I change value to lowercase it still be how it should be.
I try to be more clear
It is contact page submit button

`<input type="submit" name="commit" value="send">`

I don't know why but in jsfiddle this code below works fine but not in my code where it is all capitalized . I'm using less btw.

```
input[type=submit] {
  text-transform: capitalize;
 }
```

Comment: Clearly this does work so you must have something else going on. If you can make a demo reproducing the problem we can help  but if you can't, there is little we can do.

Comment: Well i made class in it and then capitalize text-transfrom works
`.someclass {
  text-transform: capitalize;
 }`

Comment: So it sounds like a specificity issue.

Comment: Its not what I looking for but that will do for now

Comment: Do you want this to display upon inputting it or outputting or both?

Answer (score 6):

Use `text-transform: capitalize;` for `input[type=submit]`.

```css
input[type=submit] {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="send">
```

Comment: It made whole word uppercase

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
.capitalize {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
 
.uppercase {
     text-transform: uppercase;
}

.lowercase {
   text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

```html
<input type="Submit" value="Submit" class="uppercase" />
```

Comment: Made whole word uppercase some reason

Comment: it should be like a button not textfield, i want submit button start always with uppercase. Like i did with regular buttons - used first-letter, but it don't work with input

Answer (score 0):

There is no such possibility to use pseudo element like first-letter, first-line or first-child for inputs. For buttons we can use `<button type="submit">Submit</button>` instead of `<input type="submit" value="submit"/>` to use the  pseudo elements.

Answer (score -1):

Would text-transform: capitalize; help?

```
input{
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="send" style="text-transform: capitalize;">
```

apply style:`style="text-transform: capitalize;"`